# Have dozens of Palestinian Authority officials committed terror attacks against Israelis "in the past few months" (2023-2024)?

Tags: israel, terrorism, palestine

A February 25 Fox News [article has](https://www.foxnews.com/world/biden-vision-for-palestinian-state-doomed-experts-an-explicit-recognition-of-hamas) extensive quotes and paraphrases from an interview with Prof. Efraim Inbar, President of the Jerusalem Institute for Strategy and Security, who among other things says:

> Even Fatah, the Palestinian political faction led by the current Palestinian Authority President Mahmoud Abbas, "are not the nicest of neighbors," he said, noting that, **in the past few months "dozens" of members of the [Palestinian] Authority’s official security forces have carried out terror attacks against Israelis** [...].

Is this true? Have there been dozens of PA officials (which is not Hamas, BTW) who carried out terror attacks against Israelis, in the closing months of 2023 and beginning of 2024?

Answer (score 1):

Since the start of the war on Oct 7<sup>th</sup> until now more than [49* members of the PA security apparatus were killed by IDF or other Israeli forces](https://abualiexpress.com/en/en23001/).

As per previous comments this answer address the original claim more than the question asked by OP, as they differ in their interpretation of certain words.

I'll start by defining words. In the Israeli day to day language a "terrorist" and a "terror attack" is not reserved only to attacks on civilians but to any attack on Israeli civilians, Israeli infrastructure or Israeli military personal. One example of this is [this (Hebrew) news article](https://www.ynet.co.il/news/article/bjvu006m7p) where an attack on an IDF force is described as a terror attack and the attackers as terrorists:

> פיגוע ירי בשומרון: מחבלים פתחו באש על כוח של צה"ל, חייל נפצע קל
>
> מחבלים שהגיעו במכונית לעמדת צה"ל ליד הכפר נבי אליאס פתחו באש. חייל נפצע קל. הכוחות השיבו בירי ופתחו במרדף אחרי המחבלים הנמלטים

> ‎Shooting [terror] attack in Samaria: Terrorists opened fire on an IDF force, lightly wounding a soldier‎
>
> ‎Terrorists who drove up to an IDF post near the village of Nabi Ilyas opened fire. A soldier was lightly wounded. The forces returned fire and chased the fleeing terrorists‎

After establishing the terminology Prof. Efraim Inbar is using we can use the same definition where a terrorist is anyone who not only tries (or succeeds) harming Israeli civilians but also those who attack IDF or other Israeli military forces.

Those are only the once killed, it doesn't count those that were captured, arrested, injured or evaded. Researching the story of 49 individual cases is beyond my capabilities here and I can't give the backstory of each one of them. So I bring the once that I managed to find the circumstances behind:

---

**Update from just now (Feb. 29, 2024):**

- The perpetrator of the [Eli terror attack who murdered two citizens](https://www.timesofisrael.com/liveblog_entry/two-killed-in-terror-shooting-near-west-banks-eli-settlement-gunman-shot/) is [Muhammad Manassera, an officer in the Palestinian police](https://abualiexpress.com/en/en23426/)

---

- [Jamal Mahmoud Masharka, a Palestinian Authority intelligence officer who was injured during clashes with Israeli soldiers in Jenin on November 9, died in hospital today.](https://twitter.com/KhaledAbuToameh/status/1725590621627220348) (Nov. 17, 2023)
- [Mansour Jalal Jaber, member of the Palestinian Authority National Security Force, who carried out today's shooting attack near Nablus. He was killed by israeli troops.](https://twitter.com/KhaledAbuToameh/status/1755605808958910596) (Feb. 8, 2024)
- [The funeral of the Palestinian Aref Qadoumi who was killed during gunfire exchange with the occupation forces in Jenin refugee camp.](https://twitter.com/EyeonPalestine/status/1760246788475293725) (Feb. 21, 20242) In addition to the PA flags seen in the video, about Qadoumi's affiliation to the PA [source](https://abualiexpress.com/en/en22977/):

> The Palestinians report that in last night’s IDF operation in Jenin (which lasted until approximately three o’clock in the morning), Aref Kadumi, commander of Fatah’s al-Aqsa Martyrs Battalions in Qalqilya, was killed (killed outside his territory).
> He also previously served as a member of the PA’s security mechanisms.
> And he is also the “martyr” number 400 in the West Bank and Jerusalem since the war began.

- [The IDF and ISA Eliminate the Head of Terrorist Infrastructure of the Balata Camp in Nablus](https://www.idf.il/en/mini-sites/idf-press-releases-regarding-the-hamas-israel-war/january-24-pr/the-idf-and-isa-eliminate-the-head-of-terrorist-infrastructure-of-the-balata-camp-in-nablus/) (Jan. 16, 2024):

> During joint IDF and ISA activity in the Balata camp in the city of Nablus, a terrorist cell headed by Amed Abdullah Abu-Shalal was eliminated during a precise airstrike.
>
> ...
>
> Abdullah was also responsible for carrying out a number of terrorist attacks over the last year, including the shooting attack in the Shimon HaTzadik neighborhood in Jerusalem last April during which two Jerusalem residents were injured. Additionally, he was responsible for the bombing attack against IDF soldiers last October during which a soldier was injured.

[The Fatah movement admitted that all the men killed were its members](https://abualiexpress.com/en/the-fatah-movement-headed-by-abu-mazen-mourns-its-heroic-martyrs-the-terrorists-who-were-killed-this-morning-in-the-drone-attack-in-nablus/):

> The Fatah movement headed by Abu Mazen mourns its “heroic martyrs” – the terrorists who were killed this morning in the drone attack in Nablus.
>
> The Fatah movement officially admits that all five are its people.

[A video of the military funeral of Yazen a-Najmi](https://www.gettyimages.com/detail/video/palestinian-mourners-take-part-in-the-funeral-of-yazan-news-footage/1959140724) who was [killed together with Amed Abdullah Abu-Shalal](https://twitter.com/AbuAliEnglishB1/status/1747533818863419828)

- [Another photo of the officer in the security apparatus of the Palestinian Authority Ayham El-Amer who was killed in the exchange of fire with the IDF in Jenin.](https://abualiexpress.com/en/another-photo-of-the-officer-in-the-security-apparatus-of-the-palestinian-authority-ayham-el-amer-who-was-killed-in-the-exchange-of-fire-with-the-idf-in-jenin/)(Nov. 9, 2023)

<sub>* - Palestinians claim that 50 were killed, but one of them died in Israeli prison after being arrested and sentences in 2007 for a murder he committed in 2000 and other terror activity and is not relevant to the time frame in question [source](https://abualiexpress.com/en/en22997/).</sub>

Comment: This is a rewrite of my previous question trying to address some of the issues raised in the comments.

Comment: If someone is a commander of Fatah’s al-Aqsa Martyrs Battalions then it doesn't seem correct to count him as a "member of the Palestinian Authority’s official security forces". See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Aqsa_Martyrs%27_Brigades).

Comment: @DanRomik Fatah, Abu Mazen's political organization took responsibility for the men, and at least one of them got a full military funeral. They are a part of the PA.

Comment: The source for Mansour Jalal Jaber is a tweet by Khaled Abu Toameh. Is there a better source?

Comment: @StandwithGaza, there are probably arab sources which I can't read. That's why my sources are Hebrew and English speaking journalist who cover the Palestinian arena. What are you doubting? That he was killed, that he was a member of the PA security apparatus or that he was killed in a gun fight?

Comment: Fatah, the PA and the al-Aqsa brigades are three separate entities. There is a large amount of overlap between them, and it’s even possible that the distinction between them is largely artificial and made in order to mislead westerners into thinking the PA is more benign than it really is. Nonetheless, I don’t think you’ve provided evidence that these men are “PA officials” or “members of the PA’s official security forces”.

Comment: @DanRomik, If they get an official funeral they are official. Also, "the distinction between them is largely artificial and made in order to mislead westerners into thinking the PA is more benign than it really is", so don't be mislead by them.

Comment: @SIMEL All of the above. Imo Abu Toameh has zero credibility as a journalist and has been caught with malpractice before, but that's a different story. You may disagree, but at least state that your sources are tweets.